# MySQL find crossovers in a table for different profiles for a same user

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables one is table `Profile` and other is table `Profile_location` (stores the relation of a profile and a location). Problem:

A user can have multiple profiles, each profile has different locations. I want to find crossover of locations between each profile of a given user. In other words, evaluate all the profiles of a given user and find the locations which are not unique.

A quick help would be really appreciated.

User ID and Location ID comes from table users and location.

```
Table Profile:          Profile_ID, Profile_Name, User_ID, Other details ...
Table Profile_Location: ProLoc_ID, Location_ID(FK), Profile_ID(FK)
Table Users:            User_ID, Username, etc.
Table Location:         Location_ID, Location_Name, etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  l.Location_ID,
  l.Location_Name
FROM
  Location l
WHERE
  EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
        FROM Profile p
  INNER JOIN Profile_Location pl ON pl.Profile_ID = p.Profile_ID
             AND pl.Location_ID = l.Location_ID
       WHERE p.User_ID = <USER_ID_PARAM>
    GROUP BY pl.ProLoc_ID
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  )
```

Comment: unknown column l since Location l doesn't exist in that context of subquery. I am running it as mysql query. Not sure if it's ok for SQL Server

Comment: It *should* exist. MySQL can do correlated sub-queries and it is defined on the outer query, after all.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Tom. Here is what I have got:

[SQL] select 
 tbl_region.id,
 tbl_region.`name`
from tbl_region
where
 EXISTS(
  select 1
   from tbl_profile
 INNER JOIN tbl_profile_location ON tbl_profile_location.profile_id = tbl_profile.id
       AND tbl_profile_location.region_id = tbl_region.id
    where tbl_profile.user_id = 109
  GROUP BY tbl_profile_location.id
   having COUNT(*) > 1
)

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'tbl_region.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: @Shahan: Okay. [The MySQL docs state that this construct should be possible](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html). **a)** Can you get the inner query to run by itself? (just substitute the `tbl_region.id` with an actual region ID) **b)** Try to move the `AND tbl_profile_location.region_id = tbl_region.id` to the WHERE clause and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Shahan: You're welcome. Good to hear that it worked, finally.